# mysql join vs subqueries for multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

Almost most of the posts and answers suggest and recommend `JOINS` instead of `sub queries` for performance. So I am trying to implement `JOINS`, though `sub queries` has solved problem. Here, One student `id` contains multiple values in `mark` table.

**Student**

```
id  |   Roll    |   name
=========================
1   |   1       |   Smith
```

**Mark**

```
id  |   std_id  |   sub_id  |   th
==================================
1   |   1       |   1       |   60
2   |   1       |   2       |   55
```

**Subject**

```
id  |   title
=============
1   |   Science
2   |   Math
```

Now my requirement is to combine multiple values associated with each id in one div

```
Name: Smith
Science: 60
Math: 55
```

But with `join`, result is repeatedly fetching

```
Name: Smith
Science: 60

Name: Smith
Math: 55
```

I've tried `GROUP BY` to `std.id`, but it fetched only mark of first row, here the marks of `science` only.

```
$result=$con->prepare(
    "SELECT
        student.id, student.name
        subject.title AS sub,

        mark.std_id,
        mark.sub_id,
        mark.th

        FROM student
        LEFT JOIN mark ON mark.std_id = student.id
        LEFT JOIN subject ON subject.id = mark.sub_id
        WHERE student.id=:id;"
    ) or die($con->error);

    $result->bindParam(':id',$_POST['std']);
    $result->execute();
    while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $name=$row['name'];
        $sub=$row['sub'];
        $th=$row['th']; echo"
        <article id='blg_half'>
            Name: $name<br/>
            $sub : $th
        </article>";
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Doesn't work doesn't help... Do you have an error? Or do you simply not get the data you want?

Comment: Show your code with subqueries (the one that worked) as well as the one with GROUP BY that didn't

Comment: Seems like your query is fine, it's the way that you're displaying the results that's the problem.  You need to add logic to only display the name when it changes from the previous entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need GROUP BY and an aggregate function (GROUP_CONCAT), like so:

```
SELECT
        student.id, student.en_name AS name, student.class, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(subject.title, mark.th))

        FROM student
        LEFT JOIN mark ON mark.std_id = student.id
        LEFT JOIN subject ON subject.id = mark.sub_id
        WHERE student.id=:id
        GROUP BY student.id
```

Comment: I'd just used `group by` only, have not idea about `group_concat`. learned new lesson. Thanks